# Cálculo de ocorrência de strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com 3 colunas `id`, `nome` e `voto`. Elas estão populadas com muitos registros, e preciso de um cálculo que me retorne o **nome com melhor "saldo" de votos**. A coluna `voto` só pode receber valores como 'sim' e 'não', sendo do tipo string.

O que preciso é verificar a quantidade de 'sim' e 'não' de todos os registros e retorna quem deles tiver um maior saldo. Se tiver um sim, acrescenta um ponto, caso não, retira-se um ponto. Não estou conseguindo trabalhar com strings.

Estou usando o SQL Server

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso acima preciso que volte o nome da **Ann**, pois tem um melhor saldo de pontos

OBS.: os ids são únicos e os nomes podem se repetir

Comment: Como são essas tabelas, os ids são únicos e os nomes se repetem, ou id e nomes  se repetem?

Comment: vou botar uma imagem para esclarecer melhor

Comment: me equivoquei na pergunta, não é para retornar o id, e sim o nome

Comment: Quando você diz 'saldo' o você quer dizer a diferença entre Sim e Não?

Comment: Isso. Caso o numero de sim seja maior, dará um saldo positivo, senão será negativo ou nulo quando o sim e o não forem iguais

Comment: A resposta do Daniel esta correta. Exceto, por um detalhe:
`SELECT nome, SUM(CASE WHEN voto = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS Total FROM tabela GROUP BY Nome order by Total desc` desse modo o select ficará ordenado corretamente pelo saldo. Apenas que não será nulo,  mas zerado quando ambos forem iguais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seja isso que procuras:

```
   SELECT TOP 1 name, SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS Total 
   FROM table1 
   GROUP BY Name 
   ORDER BY Total desc
```

EDIT2: Não reparei seu edit, você quer apenas o usuario com maior saldo como o GOKU SSJ4 pontuou. 
Adicionado TOP 1 a query.

Comment: (No caso acima preciso que volte o nome da Ann, pois tem um melhor saldo de pontos)  ... TOP 1 se for preciso retorna apenas um.

Comment: perfeito pessoal!